# Healing macro for RIFT with mouseover and focus handled?

Tags: rift

I am trying to create a healing macro for RIFT that does the following:

1. If I have the mouse over a friendly target, it should heal that target
2. If I don't have the mouse over a friendly target, and I have focus set, it should heal the focus
3. If it comes here, it doesn't really matter what it does, whether the macro does nothing or it heals me or something completely different

What I tried:

```
#show Healing Breath
cast @mouseover Healing Breath
cast @focus Healing Breath
```

What happens is that it never heals focus. It will either heal my mouseover target, or it seems the first cast line there falls back to me if it doesn't have a mouseover target, never reaching the third line for focus.

Is there any way to do what I want, other than to break up the macro into two?

Comment: Hey, @Lasse.  I've removed the extra tags, as they weren't needed.

Comment: I believe it's trying to cast on your mouseover target, which ends up being the floor, so it defaults to you? If you remove the third line, does the same behaviour still happen? (yes this is a super-necropost)

Comment: @Corsaka Unfortunately, I stopped playing RiFT a long time ago, so I can't really respond to your comment any more. Perhaps someone else will necro this post in the future with a response for you :)

Answer (score 0):

Macros in Rift are executed in sequence, not using any sort of logic structure. This means that if your first condition is met (ie: skill is off cooldown and your mouse is over a friendly target) the skill associated with the mouseover will execute and the macro stops. My guess is if you switched the order of your 2nd and 3rd lines, it will work as you intended.

Comment: That would mean that he only heals a mouseover target if no focus target is set, rather than only healing the focus target if not hovering over a mouseover target.